# Spring ACL & Inheritance

Tags: spring, inheritance, acl

I'm currently evaluating spring ACL for a web project. The domain model (JPA) of the project consists basically of a hierarchy starting with Company -> Client -> Product and so on. Users (which are members of a company) of the app are only allowed to see Products which belong to their Company.

I don't see any other way than assigning each Company it's own Role (e.g. ROLE_COMPANY_A, ROLE_COMPANY_B, etc), which is persisted more or less hardcoded in the ACL-tables (This is most probably not the best design; open for suggestions...)

While I was able to hook up the Spring ACL with the JPA Layer (Aspect on the various Repository's save()-Methods), I have troubles finding the proper parent ACL Object when inserting a new Entity. To find out to which Company an Entity belongs I must traverse the Object-hierarchy to find the proper Role (i.e. ROLE_COMPANY_A) within the Aspect (which is even worse, since an Aspect should not contain any app-knowledge).

So the question is, if anyone has used spring ACL in a scenario like this one? Since we are not bound to spring ACL, another solution/framework may also be considered. Bascially I really want to avoid the traversal of the object hierarchy to find out the proper Role.

tnx & regards

Comment: Why do you need to traverse? If the user is logged in, then the users roles can be retrieved from Spring-Security.

Comment: Yeah, but the user's role is not sufficient. I also need to know the entity's role to know if the entity may be displayed to the user (in this case: Does the entity belong to company A?)